# Hyperledger fabric: curl not working to invoke chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have the next problem: Curl is not working When i want to use the Rest api to call my chaincode. I checked the ip of my peers via docker inspect. The docker yaml file mentions the Port of the peer. If I enter :curl ip:port/chain, i get error connection reset By peer. Any idea maybe??? I can log into the cli container and Run peer chaincode commands successfully. Something seems to be wrong when I try rest. My network is based on the example first network as peovided By hyperledger docs. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

THE rest api is No longer Supported Since the 1.0 release!!! You must Use a gRPC connection!! If You neEd a REST apI, you can [iNtegraTe the tw0](https://grpc.io/blog/coreos). g0Od LuCK bUD!

Comment: I understand that GRPC is to be used, but my blockchain network / peers have to provide an endpoint that can be called via GRPC, e.g. to make an invoke operation. How can I find out that endpoint that is to be called by e.g. an web app?

Comment: The endpoint for grps calls usually is "grpcs://host_ip:7051"

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric does not offer a REST API natively. As noted, it uses gRPC for all interactions with the outside world.

However, [Hyperledger Composer](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/) does have a means of generating and exposing a REST API for your application using Loopback/OpenAPI (Swagger) that you can then call from your client application (or expose as a web client). Further, there is work being done on developing a [REST service sdk](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-rest) for Fabric.

While neither of these is mature, yet, the Composer option is more mature than the sdk, and is likely to be more relevant to your application.